# Archiprix 20 Book Cover: What typeface?

Tags: font-identification

[image: Archiprix 20 cover detail]

[image]

Does anyone recognize the font used on this book cover for Archiprix 20? It's like Helvetica or Alte Haas but with corners cut consistently.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered that this might not actually be a font? Looks to me like text typed using a bold sans serif font which has then been converted to outlines and manually edited in a vector image editor.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, which would be an option. From the images of the catalog I've seen it seems the same style was used for headlines of articles as well, not just the cover. But could be custom cut nevertheless.

Comment: If it's used elsewhere in the document, it might also be a custom edited font. It's possible to do this with font editing software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some ordinary bold sans serif with beveled corners.

This comes quite close to your example:

[image: Example]

In InDesign:

- Write the text with Helvetica Neue Bold.
- Adjust the tracking and kerning to the wanted result.
- Use *Type > Create Outlines* to convert the text to shapes.
- Select the outlined text and enter *Object > Corner Options*.
- Choose *Bevel* and adjust the radius to your liking.

  [image: Corner Options]